# Tradingview - Start the line at the beginning

Tags: tradingview-api

Good morning,

I would like my regression line (in orange) to automatically start at the start of the graph.

Currently, I am calculating the number of existing candles on the chart, turning that value into "text" and manually entering it into the chart settings.

```
var int total_candles = 0
if barstate.islast
    total_candles := bar_index + 1

numBars2 = math.sum(total_candles,2)
numBars = int(numBars2)
```

```
numBars // type series int
```

I get the same result with :

```
start = input.time(timestamp('1800-01-01'), title='Start calculations',group='Backtest Period')
end=input.time(timestamp('2050-01-01'), title='End calculations',group='Backtest Period')
temps = time >= start and time <= end

var numCandles = array.new_int()
array.push(numCandles, 0)

if temps
    array.push(numCandles, 1)

int result = 0
for [index, value] in numCandles
    if value == 1
        result := result+1
    result
```

[image]

Is it possible to automate this process ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: In which 'chart setting' do you enter your number of bars ? What is your aim ?

Comment: Hi G. Lebret :)

My goal is for my regression line to start automatically at the very beginning of the chart, each time the indicator loads, and each time the chart changes.

I need to retrieve the number of candles, but the script imposes a variable of type "simple int" on me and I always get a variable of type "series int". And I cannot exploit a variable of type "series int"...

Comment: I have found it !!!

countCandles = last_bar_index

:) :)